# What would be a good diagram for designing React.js UIs before writing any code?

Tags: reactjs, diagram

So basically, I mean something like UML for designing classes  in Object-Oriented programming.
How can we use a diagramming software to design (model) our UIs (Components, props, states, event etc) before writing any actual code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the https://balsamiq.cloud/ for creating the wireframes of UI before starting the actual code.You can create the mobile view screens for different mobile versions in that.Later you can work on the screens wise.

Once the UI is done you may get the clear idea of what is needed in reactjs states and props values.

Answer (score 1):

Pen and paper ... whiteboard. It might sound like I'm kidding. But I find this to be the best way to model your app. When I'm done with a whiteboard diagram, I take a photo if I need to share it.

It does two big things, imo: 1. it keeps things simple so you get the important stuff figured out without overcomplicating things so you get started coding; 2. it doesn't look too official or polished so you remember it's just a sketch. When it comes time to write your code, your established patterns and conventions should dictate your app architecture and your "wireframes" should just be a reference to look back on.

Again, just my own opinion. There is no single answer to your question.